# What fields does SmartScreen use?

Tags: windows, code-signing, smartscreen

Does anyone know what all fields SmartScreen uses for indexing application 'reputation'?
Is it just the public key? Common name as well, or...?

I am mostly interested as far as reputation continuity goes -- should I find a CA which lets me reuse the same public key at renewal, etc.

Thanks

James

Comment: As for me, SmartScreen accepts any files with digital signatures from trusted authorities. Even self signed, if you place your certificate in trusted root store.

Comment: Yes, but what is it indexing on? Which properties of the certificate does it use as keys for the reputation feature? That is my question.

Comment: What "indexing", what "reputation"? Signature may be only valid or not valid. Nothing other has the sense.

Comment: Application Reputation: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2011/03/22/smartscreen-174-application-reputation-building-reputation.aspx ... As far as indexing, I am wondering which properties of the certificate are used for the query to MS servers. Is it the public key? Is it the certificate serial number? ... This same system will be used on Win8 for desktop (link above is for MSIE).

Answer (score 0):

[This MSDN blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ieinternals/2011/03/22/everything-you-need-to-know-about-authenticode-code-signing/) doesn't directly answer the question, but suggests that there is no such thing as reputation continuity:

> "Certificate rollover occurs when your old certificate expires and you begin signing your code with a new replacement certificate; all of your reputation was accumulated against the old certificate, and hence there may be a time lag for your new certificate to acquire a good reputation."

Perhaps they're using the certificate thumbprint itself? If they used the public key to identify a publisher, this wouldn't be a problem.